# Perl How can I declare scalar variable (my) outside of loop, increment scalar variable inside loop, and use incremented variable name outside of loop

Tags: mysql, perl, loops, foreach

I'm pretty new to Perl.  I'm writing a CGI, calling a subroutine that calls another subroutine and displays HTML, in the second called subroutine I am executing a mysql select statement and setting it an array with fetchrow_array.  I'm returning that array the the subroutine that displays the HTML.

```
my @agentval = &GetAgent();
my $agentval1;

foreach (@agentval) {
    $agentval1 = $_;
}
```

I'm declaring my variable and then attempting to print each value of the erray into a scalar variable, but without declaring all 26 scalar varriables.  I'm using the variables to set the values of the fields on the displayed CGI.

I was thinking I could accomplish this with

```
my @agentval = &GetAgent();
my $agentval1;

foreach (@agentval) {
    $agentval1 = $_;
    $agentval1++;
}
```

I get requires explicit package name on anything after $agentval1 ($agentval2...n)

Like I said, I'm a total newbie.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can scope the variable in the loop as such: `for my $agentval (@agentval)`.

Comment: I know this isn't the point of the question, but is there some reason you are using CGI? Of course there are cases you have to (legacy code) but if not, you might look at any of the modern frameworks Perl has to offer. I prefer [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "increment variable name" is possible in Perl, maybe even easy to do. But it's rarely the right approach for the job.

You have ~26 values in a Perl array called `@agentval`, and you want to load them into 26 related scalars. Well, you've already done that, because an array is just a collection of scalars. When you want to access a particular value, use the `$array[index]` notation:

```
print "<input type='text' name='field10' value='$agentval[9]'>\n";
```

Here, `$agentval[9]` refers to the 10th element (because index 0 is the 1st element of an array, as it is in many other languages) of the array `@agentval`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compose a variable with all the contents of @agentval array? in this case, change the foreach loop:

```
foreach (@agentval) {
    $agentval1 .= $_;
}
```